# How to split cell array values into two columns in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, split, cell-array

I have data in a cell array as [shown in the variable viewer here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofHV2.png):

```
{[2.13949546690144;56.9515770543056],
 [1.98550875192835;50.4110852121618],
 ...}
```

I want to split it into two columns with two decimal-point numbers as:

```
2.13   56.95 
1.98   50.41
```

by removing opening and closing braces and semicolons such as `[;]`
(to do as like "Text to columns" in Excel).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your N-element cell array `C` has 2-by-1 numeric data in each cell, you can easily convert that into an N-by-2 numeric matrix `M` like so (using the [`round`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/round.html) function to round each element to 2 significant digits):

```
M = round([C{:}].', 2);
```

The syntax `C{:}` creates a [comma-separated list](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html) of the contents of `C`, equivalent to `C{1}, C{2}, ... C{N}`. These are all [horizontally concatenated](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/horzcat.html) using `[ ... ]`, then the result is [transposed](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/transpose.html) using `.'`.

Answer (score 0):

```
% let's build a matching example...
c = cell(2,1);
c{1} = [2.13949546690144; 56.9515770543056];
c{2} = [1.98550875192835; 50.4110852121618];

% convert your cell array to a double array...
m = cell2mat(c);

% take the odd rows and place them to the left
% take the even rows and place them to the right
m = [m(1:2:end,:) m(2:2:end,:)];

% round the whole matrix to two decimal digits
m = round(m,2);
```

Depending on your environment settings, you may still see a lot of trailing zeros after the first two decimal digits... but don't worry, everything is ok (on the precision point of view). If you want to display only the "real" digits of your numbers, use this command:

```
format short g;
```

Answer (score -2):

you should use cell2mat

```
A={2.14,1.99;56.95,50.41};
B=cell2mat(A);
```

As for the rounding, you can do:

```
B=round(100*B)/100;
```

Comment: OP data is a cell arraw of COLUMN vectors... your code will produce a new column vector with all the values mixed together. Also, why using that approach for rounding when you can specify the number of digits within the function?